# Get both the child row and its top root row and combine IDs and Names in a special way

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i send CatelogID then need to get the catelogID with rootcatelogName and RootCatelogID

```
CREATE TABLE catelog 
 (
 CatelogID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1),
 CatelogName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 ParentID BIGINT NULL
 )

SELECT * from catelog

INSERT INTO catelog(catelogName,ParentID)
VALUES('Embedded Sytem',NULL),
('Library',NULL),
('Books',2),
('Pages',3),
('Chapters',4),
('Paragraph',5),
('New Sytem',1),
('College',NULL)
```

When i give CatelogID as 6 then output should be like this

O/P:

```
CatelogID  RootCatelogName RootParentID 

  2          Library        NULL
  6          Library        2
```

If i dont pass any value can i get the result like this

```
CatelogID RootCatelogName   RootParentID 
 1        Embedded Sytem        NULL
 2        Library               NULL
 3        Library               2
 4        Library               2
 5        Library               2
 6        Library               2
 7        Embedded              1
 8        College               NULL
```

Comment: Could you please check your example? If I am not mistaken, 6 should produce a resultset starting at "Paragraph" and then going over "Chapters" to the first Level... Furthermore "Library" has no parent - so your output looks a bit strange anyways.

Comment: I really really tried understand the logic here, but I cannot...

Comment: No way!! I try many times to understand it , but I can't, also from where `RootCatelogName ` and `RootParentID ` come?

Comment: @LukStorms The CategoryID is Identity Column . The expectation seems to be to query the record with CatergoryId and it's root or top level parent record

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking,Edit your post to be more specific about what you're looking for, and be sure to address any concerns that other users brought up in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try hierarchy CTE

```
DECLARE @id INT = 6;

WITH h AS (
  SELECT CatelogID,catelogName,ParentID
  FROM catelog
  WHERE CatelogID = @id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT p.CatelogID,p.catelogName,p.ParentID
  FROM h
  JOIN catelog p ON p.CatelogID = h.ParentID
)
SELECT t.* 
FROM h
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT @ID AS catelogID, catelogName AS RootCatelogName, CatelogID AS RootParentID 
  UNION 
  SELECT CatelogID, catelogName AS RootCatelogName, ParentID AS RootParentID 
  ) t
WHERE ParentID IS NULL;
```

Returns

```
    catelogID   RootCatelogName RootParentID
        2       Library         NULL
        6       Library         2
```

**EDIT**

The query to answer your second question

```
WITH h AS (
  SELECT CatelogID AS leafId, CatelogID, catelogName, ParentID
  FROM catelog
  WHERE ParentID IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT h.leafId, p.CatelogID, p.catelogName, p.ParentID
  FROM h
  JOIN catelog p ON p.CatelogID = h.ParentID
)
SELECT leafId AS catelogID, catelogName AS RootCatelogName, CatelogID AS RootParentID 
FROM h
WHERE ParentID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT CatelogID,catelogName,ParentID
FROM catelog
WHERE ParentID IS NULL
ORDER BY CatelogID;
```

Returns

```
catelogID   RootCatelogName RootParentID
    1       Embedded Sytem  NULL
    2       Library         NULL
    3       Library         2
    4       Library         2
    5       Library         2
    6       Library         2
    7       Embedded Sytem  1
    8       College         NULL
```

Comment: How do you know `RootCatelogName ` and `RootParentID` is aliases?

Comment: @Sami I just cann't imagine any other version.

Comment: Thank you so much .

Comment: if i dont pass any value can i get the output as like this??CatelogID RootCatelogName RootParentID 
 1  Embedded Sytem  NULL
 2  Library    NULL
 3  Library    2
 4  Library    2
 5  Library    2
 6  Library    2
 7  Embedded   1
 8  College    NULL

Comment: Please edit your question to show output needed for the later case.

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive CTE and row_number to get the top level :

```
declare @CatelogID BIGINT = 6;

;with cte as 
( 
    select CatelogID as BaseCatelogID, CatelogName as BaseCatelogName, 0 as level, CatelogID, CatelogName, ParentID 
    from catelog t
    where CatelogID = @CatelogID

    union all

    select cte.BaseCatelogID, cte.BaseCatelogName, level + 1, t.CatelogID, t.CatelogName, t.ParentID 
    from cte
    join catelog t on (cte.ParentID = t.CatelogID)
)
, cte2 as
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by BaseCatelogID order by level desc) as rn 
    from cte
)
select CatelogID, CatelogName as RootCatelogName, ParentID as RootParentID
from cte2 where rn = 1
union all
select BaseCatelogID, CatelogName, CatelogID
from cte2 where rn = 1;
```

Returns:

```
CatelogID  RootCatelogName RootParentID 
  2          Library        NULL
  6          Library        2
```

Comment: Thank you so much @LukStorms . Exactly getting data how i want .